# Random number generator, int(), .get()

Tags: python, tkinter

This code just gives back an error. I don’t know how to combine `int()` and `.get()` for this random number generator. The `.get()` is meant to get the numbers entered and use those as the variables that someone would like to have a random number outputted back from those.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("random number generator")

def new_number():
    text.config(text=random.randint(0, 100), font=("times", 50))

tb1 = Entry(root)
tb2 = Entry(root)
tb1.grid(row=0, column=3)
tb2.grid(row=0, column=0)

text = tk.Label(root, text=random.randint(int(tb1.get()), int(tb2.get())), font=("times", 50))
text.grid(row=1, column=2)

button = tk.Button(root, text="New number", width=15, command=new_number, font=("times", 50))
button.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Always include the full error as formatted text into the question.

Comment: You're calling `tb1.get()` about a millisecond after creating the entry widget. It's not going to have any data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the default value. When you use:

```
text = tk.Label(root, text=random.randint(int(tb1.get()), int(tb2.get())), font=("times", 50))
```

tb1.get () and tb2.get () is empty.

Solution:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("random number generator")


def new_number():
    text.config(text=str(random.randint(int(tb1.get()), int(tb2.get()))), font=("times", 50))


tb1 = Entry(root)
tb2 = Entry(root)
tb1.grid(row=0, column=3)
tb2.grid(row=0, column=0)

tb1.insert(10, 0)
tb2.insert(10, 100)

text = tk.Label(root, text=str(random.randint(int(tb1.get()), int(tb2.get()))), font=("times", 50))
text.grid(row=1, column=2)

button = tk.Button(root, text="New number", width=15, command=new_number, font=("times", 50))
button.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `.insert(10, ...)` to `.insert("end", ...)`. I have no idea why you are using `10` there. It makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You must insert an integer for the `tb1` and `tb2` entry widgets. When you defined the variable `text`, you tried to get the int of `tb1`, which didn't work because there was nothing in it. So, you should insert an integer before making the `text` variable.

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("random number generator")

def new_number():
  text.config(text=random.randint(0, 100), font=("times", 50))


tb1 = Entry(root)
tb2 = Entry(root)
tb1.grid(row=0, column=3)
tb2.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Insert a number to each input box
tb1.insert(END, 1)
tb2.insert(END, 2)


text = tk.Label(root, text=random.randint(int(tb1.get()), int(tb2.get())), font=("times", 50))
text.grid(row=1, column=2)

button = tk.Button(root, text="New number", width=15, command=new_number, font=("times", 50))
button.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("random number generator")

def new_number():
    try:
        lower_bound = int(tb1.get())
        upper_bound = int(tb2.get())
        assert upper_bound >= lower_bound, "Make sure that the lower bound is lower"
        text.config(text=random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound))
    except AssertionError:
        text.config(text="Lower abound must be lower")
    except ValueError:
        text.config(text="Invalid data")

tb1 = Entry(root)
tb2 = Entry(root)
tb1.grid(row=0, column=0)
tb2.grid(row=0, column=3)



text = tk.Label(root, text="Random number", font=("times", 50))
text.grid(row=1, column=2)

button = tk.Button(root, text="New number", width=15, command=new_number,
                   font=("times", 50))
button.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

It will handle all of the errors.